# Dropdown working in Chrome not Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown in my header that works just fine in Chrome. But when I use firefox, I am able to click on the button and have the dropdown appear but I am unable to click on the forms inside. And when I try to click on the actual dropdown it simply goes back up, as if I had clicked off someplace else.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="dropdown" >
<a id="welcome_dropdown_toggle" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
  <ul id="welcome_page_dropdown" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-nav pull-right " >
  <%= form_for(:user, url: session_path(:user), :html => {:class => 'form-group login-name', :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group login-name">
      <div class="input-group " style="margin-bottom: 12px;">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
         <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Email', :type => 'text' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group login">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
           <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Password', :type => 'password' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label class="string optional remember-text" for="user_remember_me">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
     <%= link_to 'Forgot Email/Password?', new_password_path(:user) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</ul> <!--dropdown-menu -->
</div> <!-- dropdown -->
```

**CSS**

```
     #welcome_dropdown_toggle{
      margin-right:15px;
      float: right;
      height: 50px;
      width: 150px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      border: none;
      background-color: white;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 8px;
   }
   #welcome_dropdown_toggle:hover{
      color:#2b2625;
   }

   #welcome_page_dropdown{
    padding: 15px; 
    padding-bottom: 15px; 
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-right:15px;
   }
```

**Edit 1**

So in an attempt to fix it, I was removing random classes and id's from the div's. As a result of moving one of them, The dropdown would appear covering part of the actual "sign in" button. What was interesting about this, was that I could click on the part of the dropdown that was covering the button but nothing else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the item below the dropdown (which was full width and several hundred px tall, had a `position:relative;` but no z-index. When I added `z-index:1;` to the wrapper of the div bellow it, I was able to click on the forms and the full dropdown again.

I find this kind of odd, I was able to see the dropdown so I had assumed that z-index was not needed. Also the fact that chrome and ff handle that situation differently is also interesting.